# #1062 - Duplicate entry '1' in wordpress plugin table

Tags: mysql, wordpress, database-migration, mysql-error-1062

When I'm importing a dump file from another existing website, it shows me the following error:

```
-- Duming data for table 'wp_cimy_uef_data'
--
INSERT INTO 'wp_cimy_uef_data' ('ID', 'USER_ID', 'FIELD_ID', 'VALUE') VALUES
(1, 1, 1, '');
--
#1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key PRIMARY (ID)
```

I've checked and there is an AUTO_INCREMENT on the ID. What can be the problem?

BTW,
the plugin works just fine in the original website, only after dumping the DB to the new site it happens

Comment: Is there a row in the table with an id of 1?

Comment: @juergend you can tell it is complaining about the `ID` based on the error `Duplicate entry '1' for key PRIMARY (ID)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to insert a `1` into the `ID` field rather than letting it be assigned by the `AUTO_INCREMENT`, and there is already an entry in your database with an `ID` value of `1`.

Omit the `ID` in your columns and values to have it auto assigned.

```
INSERT INTO 'wp_cimy_uef_data' ('USER_ID', 'FIELD_ID', 'VALUE') 
VALUES (1, 1, '');
```